# Where can I find a function inside an MVC Web App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

If I have something like `@LT.Models.Helper.GetName()` in the `.cshtml` file... where is that located? I didn't see a `Helper` file inside the `Models` folder. Thanks.

The only thing I see inside `Models` is a `.edmx.diagram` file.

I am trying to see the content for `GetName()` function.

Thanks.

Comment: are you not able to f12 on the function name or do a global search?

Comment: That's the thing... I searched the entire solution for `GetName()`... no result! It baffles me. It was built by another person who is not here.

Comment: show your search options, ensure you are saying search in all file times

Comment: Ctrl + F.... I change Current Document to Entire Solution.

Answer (score 0):

ensure u say search all types of files.... along with Look in ...

[image]

why not just write that method into a cs file and then f12 it or ctrl dot... and see if it suggests somethere to include from...

start looking for namespace and dll which follow which dll it may be coming from..

is it not a local function to the file... include the entire file.. its should give more clues